# Deleting rows without overloading the database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-administration

The table contains about 100m rows of data per year.
I wanted to remove all data except for last 2 years of data.
Data starts from 2017.
To do so, instead of simple delete, I used while loop for delete top 10,000 rows.
During the process, I was wondering, how can I observe the best number of rows to be deleted per loop?
How can I do so without leaving trail in transaction log?
I want to loop delete with most efficiency without burdening the database.

```sql
DECLARE
@TargetDT VARCHAR(10),@Counter INT = 1
SET @TargetDT = '2018-01-01'

WHILE (@Counter <= 100)
BEGIN
delete top(10000) from  MYTABLE where DATE_COLUMN < @TargetDT 
SET @Counter = @Counter + 1
END
```

I tried different number of rows to be deleted per loop: 500, 1000, 2000, 5000, 10000

Comment: *"How can I do so without leaving trail in transaction log?"* you can't; information about changes is *always* written to the transaction log. Perhaps what you are really asking is how do you avoid this being written to the transaction log and then the subsequent log backups?

Comment: *"During the process, I was wondering, how can I observe the best number of rows to be deleted per loop?"* [`@@ROWCOUNT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)?

Comment: Do you use full recovery model?

Comment: You're deleting the majority of the table.... don't do that, copy the required rows to a new table, drop the original and rename.

Comment: Also if you are going to copy the rows to keep to a new table anyway consider if you should introduce a partition scheme on date whilst you're at it to make future purges by date painless

Comment: Copying the latest data to another table then dropping the previous table is a great idea but unfortunately, the situation is that I don't have enough room to play around with space wise.

Comment: @Thom A, I see. I was hoping there was an option to just remove/skip certain part in transaction log since I am fully aware the data doesn't need to be rolledback.

Comment: *"I don't have enough room to play around with space wise."* But you do have space for your transaction log to grow..?

Comment: @Thom A, same goes for the transaction log. I will probably just do whole lot of simple recovery model backups.
The main question was more on what is the optimal amount of rows to be deleted per time

Comment: Simple recovery model backups aren't going to help you here. Why do you feel backing up the *entire* database multiple times is going to help with storage issue problems?

Comment: I was thinking backup & shrink log would allow me to keep ldfs in low size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The best method is not to delete at all.** This can be very slow, cause huge amounts of transaction log growth, and if you try to `SHRINK` the log you can get even more problems.

Instead, copy the data you need into a new table then do a switcheroo and drop the other table.

The best way to do the switcheroo is not to use `sp_rename`, but instead to use `ALTER TABLE SWITCH`. For this it's best to use two separate staging tables, which have the exact same definition as the main table.

Switch your database to bulk-logged, which means big inserts get much less logging. Use the `TABLOCK` hint on the `INSERT` for minimal logging, as well as parallel insert.

```sql
CREATE TABLE Staging1 (
  -- exact same columns, types, nullable
  -- exact same primary, unique, foreign keys, check constraints
);

CREATE TABLE Staging2 (
  -- exact same columns, types, nullable
  -- exact same primary, unique, foreign keys, check constraints
);

INSERT Staging2 WITH (TABLOCK)
  (ColumsHere)
SELECT ColumnsHere
FROM YourTable
WHERE whatever;  --all data to keep
```

If you are constantly inserting then you need to find a way to keep the new table in sync while copying (maybe using triggers). You can also use `SNAPSHOT ISOLATION` to avoid blocking the old table.

---

Now you can do the switch

```sql
SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON;      -- force immediate rollback if session is killed

BEGIN TRAN;

ALTER TABLE YourTable SWITCH TO Staging1
WITH ( WAIT_AT_LOW_PRIORITY ( MAX_DURATION = 1 MINUTES, ABORT_AFTER_WAIT = BLOCKERS ));
-- not strictly necessary to use WAIT_AT_LOW_PRIORITY but better for blocking
-- use SELF instead of BLOCKERS to kill your own session

ALTER TABLE Staging2 SWITCH TO YourTable
WITH (WAIT_AT_LOW_PRIORITY (MAX_DURATION = 0 MINUTES, ABORT_AFTER_WAIT = BLOCKERS));
-- force blockers off immediately

COMMIT TRAN;
```

Finally drop or delete the old data

```sql
TRUNCATE TABLE Staging1;
```

All of this switching is entirely metadata-only, and very very fast (a matter of milliseconds). It takes up a tiny amount of logging. You also benefit by having rebuilt the indexes for the new size of data.

---

If you don't have enough space on your disk, you can add a temporary disk (internal/external SSD drive etc) and add a `FILE` to the same filegroup. Then after you truncate the old data, you can delete the file from the filegroup [as explained here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4349/how-to-remove-a-sql-server-data-file-for-a-multidata-file-database/). Do not create a new filegroup, this code won't work in that case.

Comment: Thank you for the details. Very interesting to see a way of inserting without much logging!
Couple problems with this method on my situation.
1. There is not enough diskspace for additional set of data
2. The table cannot have a single second of disconnection otherwise, it would be an operational hazard
Please let me know if there is a way to apply above scenario with avoiding my issues.

Comment: Then get another disk temporarily (an external SSD even) and add a file to the filegroup so you get more space. Then when you truncate the old data, you can delete the file from the filegroup https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4349/how-to-remove-a-sql-server-data-file-for-a-multidata-file-database/ Do not create a new filegroup, this code won't work in that case. The above code will work with a few milliseconds of downtime, however if you are constantly inserting then you need to keep the new table in sync while copying (maybe using triggers).

Answer (score 0):

We can't tell you what size batches your system will tolerate without performance implications or blocking. You'll need to figure that out based on your observations/monitoring.

You could use methodology like this to nibble away at your table over time. There are knobs and switches to allow adjustments to be made, but you will need to provide your specific criteria in the delete statement.

```
DECLARE @DummyTable TABLE (DateTime DATETIME); INSERT INTO @DummyTable SELECT TOP 90 DATEADD(YEAR,-1,GETDATE()) FROM sys.sysobjects;

/* ---- \\ ---- || ---- // ---- */

DECLARE @Message NVARCHAR(MAX), @StartTime TIME, @EndTime TIME, @BatchSize INT, @StartDateTime DATETIME = GETDATE(), @TotalRowCount INT = 0, @RowCount INT, 
        @DelaySeconds INT, @DelayTime NVARCHAR(9), @ScriptName NVARCHAR(50), @OutputToLog BIT;

SET NOCOUNT ON;

SET @ScriptName  = 'Demo Prune Script';
SET @StartTime = '13:00:00';
SET @EndTime = '05:00:00';
SET @BatchSize = 35;
SET @DelaySeconds = 5;
SET @OutputToLog = 1;

SET @Message = N'['+RIGHT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(19),GETDATE(),121),14)+N']: '+@ScriptName+N' script initiated at '+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(19),GETDATE(),121)+N' as '+SYSTEM_USER+' with parameters:
                  StartTime:    '+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8),@StartTime,121)+N'.
                  EndTime:      '+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8),@EndTime,121)+N'.
                  BatchSize:    '+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8),@BatchSize)+N'.
                  DelaySeconds: '+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8),@DelaySeconds,121)+N'.

';
IF @OutputToLog = 1 BEGIN RAISERROR (@Message, 0, 0) WITH NOWAIT, LOG; END
IF @OutputToLog = 0 BEGIN RAISERROR (@Message, 0, 0) WITH NOWAIT; END

BEGIN TRY
 WHILE CASE WHEN @StartTime < @EndTime AND CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME) BETWEEN @StartTime AND @EndTime THEN 1
             WHEN @EndTime < @StartTime AND CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME) >= @StartTime OR CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME) < @EndTime THEN 1
             ELSE 0 END = 1
   AND (@RowCount = @BatchSize OR @RowCount IS NULL)
 BEGIN
  DELETE TOP (@BatchSize) 
    FROM @DummyTable 
   WHERE DateTime < DATEADD(YEAR,-0,GETDATE());

  SET @RowCount = @@ROWCOUNT;
  SET @TotalRowCount+=@RowCount;
  IF (@RowCount > 0)
  BEGIN
   SET @Message = N'['+RIGHT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(19),GETDATE(),121),14)+N']: '+@ScriptName+N' has deleted '+ CAST(@RowCount AS NVARCHAR(10)) + N' row(s).';
   IF @Rowcount = @BatchSize SET @Message += N' Beginning delay of '+CAST(@DelaySeconds AS NVARCHAR(5))+N' second(s). ';
   SET @DelayTime = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8),DATEADD(SECOND,@DelaySeconds,CAST('00:00' AS TIME)),121);
   IF @OutputToLog = 1 RAISERROR (@Message, 0, 0) WITH NOWAIT, LOG;
   IF @OutputToLog = 0 RAISERROR (@Message, 0, 0) WITH NOWAIT;
   IF @Rowcount = @BatchSize WAITFOR DELAY @DelayTime;
  END
 END;
 
 IF @RowCount = 0
 BEGIN
  SET @Message = N'['+RIGHT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(19),GETDATE(),121),14)+N']: '+N''+@ScriptName+N' script has run out of rows to delete.';
  IF @OutputToLog = 1 RAISERROR (@Message, 0, 0) WITH NOWAIT, LOG;
  IF @OutputToLog = 0 RAISERROR (@Message, 0, 0) WITH NOWAIT;
 END;
 
 IF CASE WHEN @StartTime < @EndTime AND CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME) BETWEEN @StartTime AND @EndTime THEN 1
             WHEN @EndTime < @StartTime AND CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME) >= @StartTime OR CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME) < @EndTime THEN 1
             ELSE 0 END != 1
 BEGIN
  SET @Message = N'['+RIGHT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(19),GETDATE(),121),14)+N']: '+N''+@ScriptName+N' script is currently outside of it''s operational hours ('+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8),@StartTime,121)+N' to '+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8),DATEADD(SECOND,-1,@EndTime),121)+N') and has been stopped.';
  IF @OutputToLog = 1 RAISERROR (@Message, 0, 0) WITH NOWAIT, LOG;
  IF @OutputToLog = 0 RAISERROR (@Message, 0, 0) WITH NOWAIT;
 END;
 
  SET @Message = N'['+RIGHT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(19),GETDATE(),121),14)+N']: '+N''+@ScriptName+N' script ran for '+RIGHT('000' + CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND,@StartDateTime, GETDATE()) / 3600 AS NVARCHAR(2)), 2)+N':'+RIGHT('00' + CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND,@StartDateTime, GETDATE()) % 3600 / 60 AS NVARCHAR(2)), 2)+N':'+RIGHT('00' + CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND,@StartDateTime, GETDATE()) % 60 AS NVARCHAR(2)), 2)+N'.
                  It deleted '+CAST(@TotalRowCount AS NVARCHAR(10))+N' row(s).';
  IF @OutputToLog = 1 RAISERROR (@Message, 0, 0) WITH NOWAIT, LOG;
  IF @OutputToLog = 0 RAISERROR (@Message, 0, 0) WITH NOWAIT;
 END TRY
 BEGIN CATCH
  DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(MAX) = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @ErrorProcedure NVARCHAR(128) = ERROR_PROCEDURE(), @ErrorLine INT = ERROR_LINE(), @ErrorState INT = ERROR_STATE(), @ErrorSeverity INT = ERROR_SEVERITY(), @ErrorNumber INT = ERROR_NUMBER();
  SET @Message = N'['+RIGHT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(19),GETDATE(),121),14)+N']: '+N''+@ScriptName+N' encountered an error and was unable to continue:
                  Message: '+COALESCE(@ErrorMessage,'')+N'
                  Procedure: '+COALESCE(@ErrorProcedure,'')+N'
                  Line: '+COALESCE(CAST(@ErrorLine AS NVARCHAR(10)),'')+N'
                  It ran for '+RIGHT('000' + CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND,@StartDateTime, GETDATE()) / 3600 AS NVARCHAR(2)), 2)+N':'+RIGHT('00' + CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND,@StartDateTime, GETDATE()) % 3600 / 60 AS NVARCHAR(2)), 2)+N':'+RIGHT('00' + CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND,@StartDateTime, GETDATE()) % 60 AS NVARCHAR(2)), 2)+N'.
                  It deleted '+CAST(@TotalRowCount AS NVARCHAR(10))+N' row(s).';
  IF @OutputToLog = 1 RAISERROR (@Message, 0, 0) WITH NOWAIT, LOG;
  IF @OutputToLog = 0 RAISERROR (@Message, 0, 0) WITH NOWAIT;
  THROW;
 END CATCH;
 SET NOCOUNT OFF;
```