Isolation level to put a database in when deleting large amounts of data?
I am deleting large amounts of data from a database table and I want it to be as quick as possible.
I would like to try the following
Use MyDatabase
set transaction isolation level read uncommitted
Go
Delete from temptable where mark =2023
PRINT 'Number of rows deleted is ' + CAST(@@ROWCOUNT as char(3));

But I am not sure, is "read uncommitted" the best to set it at when deleting large amounts of data?
Will this have an impact on users if they are trying to write to the database?
Or is there a different isolation level to set it at?

" i want it to be as quick as possible" - Does your RDBMS support a single-user-mode?

"set transaction isolation level read uncommitted" <-- This will not make your deletes "go faster" - it will instead likely lead to your script incorrectly deleting the wrong rows (because it might read a non-committed row with mark = 2023 when the committed value was mark = 2024 which would have meant it wouldn't be deleted).

right , so what is the best way to delete this data ? would you please be able to help ?

"READ UNCOMMITTED" - just say no, kids.

I can't tell you what the "best" way is because you haven't posted any actual details of the the situation. For example, how many concurrent other readers and writers are using temptable? (and if temptable is actually a #temptable then why are you bothering to do this at all?). Is the mark column indexed? Is SNAPSHOT ISOLATION available as an option? Etc? Etc?

CAST(@@ROWCOUNT as char(3)); <--  casting @@ROWCOUNT to char(3) implies you're deleting less than 1,000 rows - is that actually the case, or are actually far more than 1,000 rows with mark = 2023?

temptable is NOT a temp table , its actually a table on the database that holds data , it is just called temptable.  I am doing it at a time where there are minimal users. Also i want to delete more than 1000 actually about 50Million. I put the print to see whats deleted , maybe its wrong. Are you able to change my delete statement and re-post , thankyou ?

Is your mark column indexed - or not? And what % of all the rows in the table do you expect will be deleted? Also consider if it may be faster to instead copy-over the rows you want to retain into a new table and then DROP TABLE.

there is a column that is primary key , called id. Also there are other rows that have mark = 2024 approx 80 Million, so i cant drop the table ?

If you want to keep only a small percentage of rows, consider: begin transaction; lock table old_table in exclusive mode; insert into new_table select * from old_table where <the rows I want to keep>; rename table old_table to archive_table; rename new_table to old_table; commit then at your leisure, drop archive_table.

will that prevent any user writing to the table if by chance someone tries ? cause you have a lock ?

@Bohemian I'll admit that I'm unsure how to get a proper XLOCK on an entire table - the top Google search result is this thread where they didn't have much luck. What approach would you recommend?

hmmm , im trying to minimize locks for users

@Stacey "Locks" are not all the same and "minimizing locks" is not necessarily a good thing. We want the right lock for the right circumstance - not no locks because that would just be unsafe.

so i guess the old fashioned way of just delete from where ?  could take 4-5 hours even more

@Stacey Sounds like you need an INDEX - or just postpone the delete-job until after business hours?

Working off the limited information you've provided so-far,
rather than making tha delete process as fast as possible, a reasonable alternative is to instead minimize the disruption caused by the delete process...
Step 1: See how bad the problem is...
We need an INDEX on temptable.mark which will enable us to see if it's worth deleting the rows from the table in-place, or if it's easier to copy the designated surviving rows to a new table and DROP the current table.
CREATE INDEX IX_mark ON dbo.temptable ( mark ) WITH ( ONLINE = ON );

Using WITH ONLINE = ON minimizes disruption to other concurrent users during this step.
Step 2: Get the distribution:
SELECT
    COUNT( * ) AS Count_All,
    COUNT( CASE WHEN mark =  2023 THEN 1 END ) AS Count_Condemned,
    COUNT( CASE WHEN mark IS NULL OR mark <> 2023 THEN 1 END ) AS Count_Surviving
FROM
    dbo.temptable;

Using a vibes-based descision, if Count_Condemned is greater than Count_Surviving then it's probably easier to copy-then-drop. Conversely, if Count_Condemned < Count_Surviving then just delete in-place.
Step 3 - Option A: Copy, drop, replace:
Choose this option (and do not perform Options B or C) when Count_Condemned > Count_Surviving:
Important: Ensure you get the definitions of all INDEX, KEY, CONSTRAINT, DEFAULT, IDENTITY, etc table paraphernalia from dbo.temptable before you continue any further, because the next T-SQL script will permamently and irrevocably delete the dbo.temptable (unless you had backups, (right?) - you can use SSMS's Script Object as CREATE to... feature to get an overview of the table, but it won't include all related objects unless you enable them in SSMS Options.
SET XACT_ABORT ON;

BEGIN TRANSACTION t3a;

SELECT
    t.*
INTO
    dbo.temptable2 
FROM
    dbo.temptable AS t
WHERE
    t.mark IS NULL
    OR
    t.mark <> 2023;

-- TODO: Re-CREATE any other INDEXes, CONSTRAINTS, and other objects/annotations, as SELECT INTO only carries-over column type information.
-- *ESPECIALLY* your primary-key (especially if clustered)
CREATE INDEX IX_mark ON dbo.temptable2 ( mark ) WITH ( ONLINE = ON );

DROP TABLE dbo.temptable;

EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.temptable2', 'temptable';

COMMIT TRANSACTION t3a;

Step 3 - Option B: Single DELETE through dbo.temptable:
The CREATE INDEX IX_mark from earlier should mean deleting even millions of rows all-at-once fairly quick.
If the DELETE FROM statement here is slow, check for any TRIGGER objects or additional INDEX objects and disable them as appropriate while this TXN runs.
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET XACT_ABORT ON;

BEGIN TRANSACTION t3b;

DELETE FROM
    dbo.temptable
WHERE
    t.mark = 2023;

COMMIT TRANSACTION t3b;

Step 3 - Option C: Batched DELETE through dbo.temptable without any long-held transactions:
This approach will allow other readers/writers access to dbo.temptable during the gaps between DELETE batches, but the overall process will take longer. It also introduces the risk that other readers/writers that aren't using row-level locks of their own will be working with quite ephemeral data right before it ceases to exist...
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @totalDeleted bigint = 0;

WHILE( EXISTS( SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM dbo.temptable AS t WHERE t.mark = 2023 ) )
BEGIN;

    WAITFOR DELAY '02:00';  

    DELETE
        TOP 10000
    FROM
        dbo.temptable
    WHERE
        t.mark = 2023;

    SET @totalDeleted = @totalDeleted + ROWCOUNT_BIG();

END;

PRINT N'Deleted ' + CONVERT( nvarchar(12), @totalDeleted ) + N' dbo.temptable rows in total.';


so which step you consider the best ?

@Stacey There is no "best" overall option: whichever alternative A, B, or C you go with is dependent on your  specific situation. I've added notes and guidance to help you decide which is the best for you - but the rest is up to you.

will try them all and see which is best and post my findings for others

@Stacey I suspect you have yet to appreciate why Options A/B/C are very much mutually-exclusive, otherwise I hope you can see that each option is an irrevocable path forward - and just look at Step 2 because Step 2 gives you the information you need to choose whether to go with A or - B or C - and choosing between B or C depends on your table's actual usage, which you haven't shared with us.

usage wat do you mean .. i have shared every thing? Its a table with over 80Million records some 50Million are mark 2023 and 30Million mark 2024. I want to delete all the rows with Mar 2023 thats it ? Mark is a daetime so i need to do Year(mark) = 2023 which may be longer to evaluate ?

on an sql database under ssms ?

I found that the count in step 2 that uses the csase statement is very quick in retrieving the count of rows instead of the traditional select count(*) from tablename.  Is there a way i can use the case statement to delete rows ?

@Stacey It's fast because of the CREATE INDEX from step 1 - it's nothing to do with the fact it's using COUNT( CASE ).

But i did not create an index, i wanted to try it without an index first

In that case you likely have nonmaintained indexes (and statistics) which will mess with query-plan selection. Check your index-fragmenation (database-wide) and rebuild them if necessary.

im not sure what does that mean ? i have to do it in batches ?

Just run this EXEC sp_msforeachtable 'SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON; ALTER INDEX ALL ON ? REBUILD'; - after it finishes you should see improved performance across-the-board.

i dont want to do it for all tables , can i not create a temporary index on the table im using and then do the delete then drop the index ?

Then do ALTER INDEX ALL ON dbo.temptable REBUILD;. (And no, there's no such thing as "temporary indexes" like we have for #temporaryTables).

Rather than sp_rename, instead do TRUNCATE TBALE original; ALTER TABLE new SWITCH TO original; See https://littlekendra.com/2017/01/19/why-you-should-switch-in-staging-tables-instead-of-renaming/

@Charlieface Interesting; thanks for the link. The article concerns SWITCH TO, but has a footnote about TRUNCATE: "The TRUNCATE TABLE command doesn’t have the WAIT_AT_LOW_PRIORITY option. Using it would put you right back in your big old blocking chain problem. A DELETE statement will be logged and also has blocking problems." - how relevant is the "blocking chain problem" described to this QA?

Not major unless there is use of the table which causes head-f-line blocking, ie there is a long-running query which holds a Sch-S lock as normal, and the ALTER waits behind it on a Sch-M. If there are no long-running queries then this is a non-issue. And can be avoided altgother by using a third table to SWITCH the old data out of original, which can use WAIT_AT_LOW_PRIORITY, then you can TRUNCATE or DROP that third table at your leisure. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/77063558/14868997
